# Sorting Counter entries by value, then by key

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I was trying to sort few values in list using Python's Counter from collection module. But it gives weird result when

```
>>> diff=["aaa","aa","a"]
>>> c=Counter(diff)
>>> sorted(c.items(), key = lambda x:x[1] , reverse=True)
[('aa', 1), ('a', 1), ('aaa', 1)]
>>> c.items()
[('aa', 1), ('a', 1), ('aaa', 1)]
```

Output is strange, as it seems to have shuffle 'aa' to the first place, then 'a' and 'aaa' at last. 
Ideally, it should have been 'a' then 'aa' then 'aaa'

What is the reason behind this and how would you rectify the same

Edit:
Most people understand the question incorrectly, Hence I am pushing some clarifications. The goal is to sort the number of words in list based on it's occurances.

Let's say list `diff = ["this", "this", "world", "cool", "is", "cool", "cool"]`. The final output by my above code would be `cool` then `this` then `is` then `world` which is correct.

but problem is when you supply same characters with same occurences, python misbehaves. As the Input is `diff = ["aaa", "aa", "a"]` , I expected output to be `a` then `aa` then `aaa` . But python algorithm would never know as every word occurred single time.

But if that is the case, then why did python didn't printed `aaa` then `aa` then `a` (i.e in same order it was inputted) giving benefit of doubt. Python sort did actually *swapped* . WHY?

Comment: Counter does not sort.  It counts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary, how to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: why not just sort the original list...? `diff.sort()`

Comment: @avigil - I am sorting based on the highest repeat of the word. :)

Comment: You *told* `sorted()` to consider ONLY the second element of each tuple.  The items were already sorted by that criterion (1 >= 1 >= 1), so no change was made to the (arbitrary) order in which the dictionary provided the items.

Comment: Let's say your Input is `diff = ["this", "world", "this", "is", "beautiful"]` the output would be accurate as this repeated 2 times and after than the priority follows based on alphabetical letters

Comment: @jasonharper - Change has been made. Look the Input is `['aaa', 'aa', 'a']` .. The output is `aa` then `a` then `aaa` . So how did python decide to swap the values in the list. Shouldn't it display `aaa` then `aa` then `a` giving python the benefit of doubt

Comment: `sorted(c.items())` creates a sorted version of the iterator returned by `items()` and returns a sorted list which in your code is being discarded. It does not sort the original `Counter` object, which is an unordered data structure and wouldn't make much sense anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a subclass of `dict`. It is an unordered collection.

The get the sorting order you want, you can update your code like -

```
sorted(c.items(), key = lambda x:(x[1], -len(x[0])) , reverse=True)
```

This gives -

```
[('a', 1), ('aa', 1), ('aaa', 1)]
```

Comment: But I am applying `sorted` function thereafter on the counted values based on the `x[1]` which is the amount of count a word is repeated. So that shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` does a [stable sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts). That means for ties, the order of items will be the same as the order they appear in the original input. Since your `Counter` is unordered, the input to `sorted` is in some undefined order. If you want you can sort by the key, and then the value:

```
sorted(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True), key = lambda x:x[1] , reverse=True)
```

Or (probably better) have your sort function return a tuple as the sort key:

```
sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x:(x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

An (even better!) version utilizing `operator.itemgetter`:

```
sorted(c.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Even better would be to use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter): `key=itemgetter(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can ensure your ordering remains unchanged.

As previously mentioned dictionaries are not deemed to be ordered. The result will be a sorted list of tuples.

```
from collections import Counter

diff = ["aaa", "aa", "a"]

c = Counter(diff)

sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: diff.index(x[0]))

# [('aaa', 1), ('aa', 1), ('a', 1)]
```

Comment: OP: "The goal is to sort the number of words in list based on it's occurances ".

Comment: @ekhumoro, User achieved his goal in his OP, so this does not seem to be so.